# Store a the number of duplicate objects

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

Is there a way with jQuery to store the order position of an element in a list of duplicate items? For example, say we have a list of 5 elements all with the same class:

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

I want to do a script that runs through `.each()` of these elements and stores the order position that it sits in the list, so then later in the same `.each()` function it will use that stored order position (number) to link up to data stored in the same position from a stored object array:

```
var object = {
  items: [
    { "test": "array1"}, 
    { "test": "array2" }, 
    { "test": "array3" }, 
    { "test": "array4" }, 
    { "test": "array5" }
  ]
};
```

So if the element order position is stored in a variable for example called `position` ( `var position =` number ) this variable will be used to match up to the data in the same position of the object array.

```
object.items[position].test; //position is the var name
```

so for the first `.item` which is in position **0**, the variable `position` will return the value **0** and fill in the script:

```
object.items[0].test;
```

which would then return the value `array1`, at this point I can complete the script with what I need.

Hopefully this all makes sense and you can help :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms you're looking for is the 'index' of the element. It is provided to `each()` in the first argument. As such you can access it directly to set the text content of each element to match the element of the array at the same index, like this:

```
$('.item').each(function(i) {
  $(this).text(object.items[i].test);
});
```

Going a step further, `text()` also allows you to provide a function to handle the content to be shown in the element, and this function also accepts the index as the first argument. Therefore the code can be simplified further still:

```js
var object = {
  items: [
    { "test": "array1"}, 
    { "test": "array2" }, 
    { "test": "array3" }, 
    { "test": "array4" }, 
    { "test": "array5" }
  ]
};

$('.item').text(function(i) {
  return object.items[i].test;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped and is very useful :)